# python: locate elements in sublists

Tags: python, nested-lists, sublist

given these sublists

```
lst=[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h']]
```

I am trying to find the location of its elements,
for instance, the letter 'a' is located at 0,0
but this line

```
print(lst.index('a'))
```

instead produces the following error:
ValueError: 'a' is not in list

Comment: `print(lst[0].index('a'))`?

Comment: @diggusbickus what if 'a' is not in the 0th sublist?

Comment: index method looks in the list you're giving him, not the sublists inside. You may loop over you sublists (in case 'a' is not (only) in the first sublist), and from the result you should know if there is 'a' in it

Comment: the problem with your solution is that I would have to manually change the parameter depending upon the letter, which entails me already knowing which sublist contains the item I am interested in.

Comment: @ metapod, is there an elegant way in python to do so without using the for loop?

Comment: I don't think so, maybe with special libraries. But i guess they will use for loops too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
>>> lst=[['a', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'a'], ['f', 'g', 'a'], ['a','a','b']]
>>> [(i,j) for i in range(len(lst)) for j in range(len(lst[i])) if lst[i][j]=='a']
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 4), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

if your `list` have `depth=2`, you can use this:

```
lst=[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h']]
def fnd_idx(char, lst):
    for x in range(len(lst)):
        try:
            idx = lst[x].index(char)
            return [x,idx]
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return None
```

Output:

```
>>> print(fnd_idx('a', lst))
[0, 0]

>>> print(fnd_idx('g', lst))
[1, 1]

>>> print(fnd_idx('z', lst))
None
```

Comment: Instead of ```len``` in the for statement, you can directly loop over the sublists: ```for sublist in lst: idx = sublist.index('a')``` with the try (I'm too lazy, sorry =) )

Comment: @Metapod and how can find an index? OP want [0,0]

Comment: It depends on whether there can be multiple occurrences of 'a' or not. If not, your method works. If there can be many, we could imagine the pos would give the index in the associated sublist of the same index. In this example, ```pos = [0, None]``` (sublist0 : 'a' at index 0, sublist1: No 'a')

Answer (score 0):

Try this function (just one line of code!):

```
def idx(lst, el):
    return next(((i, sublst.index(el))
                 for i, sublst in enumerate(lst)
                 if el in sublst),
                None)
```

So for example:

```
>>> idx(lst, 'a')
(0, 0)
>>> idx(lst, 'c')
(0, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst=[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c'], ['f', 'g', 'h']]
searchvalue = 'f'
counter = 0
for index in lst:
    if searchvalue in index:
       print(counter, index.index(searchvalue))
    counter+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'a' can appear in multiple sublists, and you want the index in each sublist:

```
def GetIndexes(lst, val):
    pos = []
    for sublist in lst:
        try:
            idx = sublist.index(val)
            pos.append(idx)
        except:
            pos.append(None)
    return pos
```

In your example : `[0, None]`
Meaning: In sublist 0, the first 'a' is at the index 0. In sublist 1, there is no 'a'.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this with numpy, the benefit is you don't have to hardcode anything for the size of nested lists. you can have hundreds or 3 and this will work!

```py
lst=[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h']]
arr = np.array(lst, dtype=object)

for x in arr:
    try:
        print (x.index('a'), x)
    except:
        pass
```